# Extracting information from a TXT file with python

Tags: python, string, text-extraction

I have a TXT file that looks like this:

```
group1

trigger: set_7  string

target: set_7  string

target: set_9  string

trigger: set_8  string

target: set_8  string

source: set_9  string

trigger: set_9  string

group2

source: set_10  string

trigger: set_10  string

target: set_10 string
```

I have to extract the trigger, target and source that correspond to each set. Each set contains at least one trigger, but it doesn't always contain a source or a target. I would like to print the the values corresponding to each set as a row with columns, leaving the empty values as NONE, something like:

```
set_7  trigger:string target:string  source:NONE
...

set_10 ...
```

Any idea of how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see what you've tried so far based on your own research, what the result was, and how that result was different from what you need

Comment: I was not able to arrive to any solution, that's why I didn't add that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One crude solution could be this (using `re` module and `itertools.groupby`):

```
txt = '''


group1

trigger: set_7 string

target: set_7 string

target: set_9 string

trigger: set_8 string

target: set_8 string

source: set_9 string

trigger: set_9 string

group2

source: set_10 string

trigger: set_10 string

target: set_10 string

'''

import re
from itertools import groupby

s = sorted( re.findall(r'(.*?):.*?set_(\d+)\s+(.*)', txt), key=lambda k: int(k[1]) )

for v, g in groupby(s, lambda k: int(k[1])):
    d = {x: y for x, _, y in g}
    print('set_{} trigger: {} target: {} source: {}'.format(v, d.get('trigger', 'NONE'),
                                                               d.get('target', 'NONE'),
                                                               d.get('source', 'NONE')))
```

This prints:

```
set_7 trigger: string target: string source: NONE
set_8 trigger: string target: string source: NONE
set_9 trigger: string target: string source: string
set_10 trigger: string target: string source: string
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me too. If possible, could you comment a bit on what each of the parts do? This way I can learn on my own how to apply this type of solutions in the future ;)